# C: Defining array using * vs [ ]. Context: Updating array argument in function

Tags: c

In this picture, why do you have to define `retArr = twoSum()`? Why can't you just pass in `retArr` into `twoSum()` as you've declared the pointer in `main()`, and expect it to be updated automatically when the `twoSum()` function exits?

I know C uses call by value and not call by reference so the values are copied in the function and are different from main, but when I define `retArr[]` as an array using square brackets (`[]`), then my retArr has the updated values from `twoSum()`?

Why is there this discrepancy when defining an array using pointers vs `[]` square brackets?

```
int arr[] = {1,2,4,9};
int retArr[2];
twoSum(arr,4,9,retArr);
```

[image]

Comment: In the case of `int * retArr`, you're not defining an array.

Comment: and don't post code in images. Copy and paste them here

Comment: You can use the `edit` button below your question to replace the graphics with your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to return retArr (**allocated in callee function**) from twoSum you can either return it via function return value or via pointer to pointer parameter (int** in your case). In second case you need to change function signature. You correctly mentioned that C passes arguments by value. Therefore twoSum will change its local copy of retArr (in your signature of twoSum). main function won't see updated value. Following example shows how to return array allocated in callee function for usage in caller function.

```
void f(int ** retArr) // retArr == #3096
{
    int *ar = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * 2); // ar == #4020
    // ...
    ar[0] = 42;
    ar[1] = 43;
    *retArr = ar; // writes #4020 to the memory cell with address #3096
}

void main()
{
    int *retArr = NULL;
    f(&retArr); // &retArr == #3096
    printf("%d %d\n", retArr[0], retArr[1]);
}
```

Following picture illustrates the notion of pointer to pointer to double:
[image]

So when you pass *int callee function twoSum copies argument to local stack, changes local value in its stack frame and this stack frame is destroyed after twoSum finishes. main argument stays intact. In case of pointer to pointer (**int) you pass value #3096 (in terms of picture), callee function copies this value #3096 locally. Then callee allocates array, obtain address #4020 , dereferences retArr and assign #4020 to caller variable retArr. Now main has address #4020 obtained from malloc.

To understand why we need pointer to pointer consider this example. Say you defined variable `char c` in caller function and want to change it in callee function. For that you pass pointer to c to callee: `callee(char *pc)`. Then in callee you write `*pc = 'a'`; This writes 'a' to variable c defined in caller function. Right? The same with variable `int * retArr` defined in caller - to be able to change variable in callee you need to pass pointer to retArr to callee. The type of retArr is "pointer to int". So you need to pass pointer to "pointer to int".
When memory is allocated by callee you need to use memory with lifetime longer than lifetime of callee - you can't use stack. In your case memory is allocated in heap using malloc. And address is assigned to pointer to int. Syntax with [] defines array on stack if definition is placed within function and in static memory if definition is placed outside any function (global variable).

Another approach is to **allocate array in caller** (outer) function:

```
void f(int *out_arr, int n )
{
    // code that fills each cell of out_arr
}

void main( void )
{
    int x[n];
    f((int *)x, n );
}
```

Comment: So based on the pointer diagram and your first chunk of code. Why do we need a double pointer in the function since a single pointer points to the memory location of the variable. Also why do we need the `&` when passing in `f(&retArr)`? I'm a little confused by this

Comment: in terms of picture: #4020 is the address obtained by malloc. You need to send #4020 to main. This can be achieved by using a pointer. &retArr gives #3096. invoking f passes #3096 to f local variable retArr. f can't change the value of the argument. So f writes #4020 to the cell with address #3096.

Comment: f can't change the value of the argument passed to f (because arguments are passed by value in C). But f can change the value of the memory using address passed to f as argument.

Comment: To change memory outside the callee function's stack frame we need to obtain address of this memory - pointer. because this memory (in your case) is "pointer to int" we need to pass pointer to "pointer to int"

Comment: Callee to change variable defined in caller function should obtain address (pointer) to this variable. To change such variable you can't pass it directly because C passes arguments by value - all transformations will be performed with local copy of argument and argument will be intact after callee finishes. In your case the caller's variable is **pointer to int**. Therefore to change this variable inside f you need to pass pointer to this variable - that is pointer to **pointer to int**.

Comment: To understand why we need pointer to pointer consider this example. Say you defined variable `char c` in caller function and want to change it in callee function. For that you pass pointer to c to callee: `callee(char *pc)`. Then in callee you write `*pc = 'a'`; This writes 'a' to variable c defined in caller function. Write? The same with variable `int * retArr` defined in caller - to be able to change variable in callee you need to pass pointer to retArr to callee. The type of retArr is "pointer to int". So you need to pass pointer to "pointer to int".

Comment: @Ken I'm glad it helped =)

Answer (score 1):

First and most important point to remember - In C, arrays are not pointers.

> *why do you have to define retArr = twoSum()? Why can't you just pass in retArr into twoSum() as you've declared the pointer in main(), and expect it to be updated automatically when the twoSum() function exits?*

The author of function `twoSum()` is a noob. The way `twoSum()` function has been written, there is no need of `retArr` parameter. Moreover, there are paths of execution in `twoSum()` which end up returning nothing from the function. Compiler must have given warning for that, something like this - `control may reach to end of blah-blah function....`. The code shown in question is equivalent to this:

```
int * twoSum(int * nums, int numSize, int target) {
    int * retArr = (int *) malloc (sizeof(int) * 2);
    ....
    // rest of code
    ....
    return retArr; // This is needed as the function should return something of type int * from all path of executions
}
```

In order to allocate memory to a pointer passed as an argument to a function, you need to pass the *address* of that pointer so that, in the function, you should be able to access the pointer, passed as argument, and allocate memory to it.

**Explanation in detail:**

For ease of understanding, doing two changes (though, none of them will make any difference) -

- Assigning `NULL` to the `retArr` pointer which is passed as argument to `twoSum()` function.
- Renaming the `twoSum()` function `retArr` parameter as `twoSum_retArr`.

  ```
   int * retArr = NULL;

   retArr
    ----
    |  |---------> NULL 
    ----
   100 [address]
  ```

## This is happening in the code you have shown in the question:

`retArr` pointer passed as argument to `twoSum()` -

```
   retArr = twoSum(/*whatever*/, retArr);
```

Since, the `retArr` set to `NULL`, the parameter `twoSum_retArr` of `twoSum()` will receive `NULL` -

```
    twoSum_retArr
    ----
    |  |----------> NULL
    ----
   200  [address]
```

Note that `twoSum_retArr` is local pointer variable of `twoSum()` function.

In this case, allocating memory to `twoSum_retArr` will be locally accessible because `twoSum_retArr` is a local variable of `twoSum()`. And that's why the
author of `twoSum()` returned it from `twoSum()` function to make the allocated
memory accessible from the calling function via the pointer receiving the
`twoSum()` returned pointer.

## If you want to allocate memory to the pointer passed to `twoSum()`:

Address of `retArr` pointer should be passed as argument to `twoSum()` -

```
   twoSum (/*whatever*/, &retArr);
```

There parameter `retArr` in `twoSum()` should be of type `int **` -

```
   twoSum ((/*whatever*/, int ** twoSum_retArr);
```

There parameter `twoSum_retArr` in `twoSum()` will receive the address of `retArr` parameter passed -

```
   twoSum_retArr     retArr
    -----              ----
    |100|--------------|  |-------> NULL
    -----              ----
   200                100
```

When you dereference the `twoSum_retArr`, you will get `retArr` pointer i.e.

```
   twoSum_retArr     retArr
    -----              ----
    |100|--------------|  |-------> NULL
    -----              ----
   200              100 ^
                        |
        *twoSum_retArr -+
        ^
        |
  (dereferencing twoSum_retArr will give retArr pointer)
```

So, when you allocate memory to `*twoSum_retArr`, you are actually allocating memory to `retArr` pointer in `twoSum()` function.

Implementation will be like this:

```
void twoSum(int * nums, int numSize, int target, int ** twoSum_retArr) {
    // dereferencing the retArr (*retArr) will give the pointer passed as argument
    *twoSum_retArr = (int *) malloc (sizeof(int) * 2);
    ....
    // rest of code
    ....
    // Access it like this
    (*twoSum_retArr)[0] = 1;
    (*twoSum_retArr)[1] = 2;
}
```

Note that, with this, there is no need to return the allocated memory reference from `twoSum()` because it is assigned to `retArr` pointer and calling function can access it via the pointer whose address is passed to `twoSum()` once `twoSum()` returned.

> *Why is there this discrepancy when defining an array using pointers vs [] square brackets?*

When you access an array, it is **converted to a pointer to initial element of array** (there are few exceptions to this rule)<sup>1)</sup>.

So, when you have `retArr` as array -

```
int retArr[2];
twoSum(arr,4,9,retArr);
```

The in-memory view of `retArr` will be like this:

```
retArr
     -----------
     |    |    |
     -----------
    100   104 [assuming int of 4 byte size]

  // 100 is base address of retArr array
```

When you pass it to `twoSum()`, the name `retArr` converted to pointer to first element of `retArr` array.

In `twoSum()`

```
twoSum ((/*whatever*/, int * twoSum_retArr);
```

`twoSum_retArr` will receive pointer to initial element of `retArr` array

```
twoSum_retArr  
  -----         -----------
  |100|-------->|    |    |
  -----         -----------
 200           100   104
```

When yo do `twoSum_retArr[0]`

```
twoSum_retArr[0] -> *(twoSum_retArr + 0) -> *(twoSum_retArr) -> *(100)
```

i.e. accessing the first member of `retArr` array, same for `twoSum_retArr[1]` accessing second member of array<sup>2)</sup>

```
twoSum_retArr[1] -> *(twoSum_retArr + 1) -> *(100 + 1) -> *(104)
```

That's why when passing array, making changes to the memory referred by passed reference, in `twoSUm()`, is reflected in the array passed to `twoSum()` by calling function.

---

1. From C11 Standards#6.3.2.1p3 [emphasis added]

> 3 Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator, the _Alignof operator, or the unary & operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, **an expression that has type ''array of type'' is converted to an expression with type ''pointer to type'' that points to the initial element of the array object** and is not an lvalue. ....

2. When you increment a pointer, it gets incremented in steps of the object size that the pointer can point to.